# How to generate values from a diagonal to fill matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following diagonal matrix

```
a = array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 2, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 3, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 4]])
```

And the desired out come is the following

```
 array([[1, 3, 4, 5],
        [3, 2, 5, 6],
        [4, 5, 3, 7],
        [5, 6, 7, 4]])
```

Each element is the sum of the corresponding diagonals.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# get diagonal
diag = np.diag(a)

# outer sum
out = diag+diag[:,None]
# or
# out = np.outer(diag, diag)

# reset diagonal
np.fill_diagonal(out, diag)

print(out)
```

output:

```
[[1 3 4 5]
 [3 2 5 6]
 [4 5 3 7]
 [5 6 7 4]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot how about in a dataframe instance using pandas

Comment: You can likely do the same. Can you provide the input/output?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
>>> np.diag(a) + np.diag(a)[:, None] - a
array([[1, 3, 4, 5],
       [3, 2, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 3, 7],
       [5, 6, 7, 4]])
```

##### Addendum

1. What if `a` is a `DataFrame`?

   Then: `np.diag(a) + np.diag(a)[:, None] - a` is also a `DataFrame` (with same index and columns as `a`).
2. What if `a` is a `numpy` array, but I want a `DataFrame` result?

   Then use: `pd.DataFrame(...)` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot how about in a dataframe instance using pandas

Comment: please see if the addendum helps.